# php urlencode for linkedin

Tags: php, api, encoding, linkedin-api

Apparently Linkedin is funny about urlencoding the ~ in https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~
my problem is that i use an oauth library so I need to keep things consistent.
is there a way to urlencode just part of the string so in case i have the ~ i can leave that out and put it back in at the same spot after encoding?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/rtrim) to remove `~` and then again append it:

```
<?php
  $URL = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~';
  echo urlencode( rtrim ( $URL, '~' ) ) . '~';
?>
```

This outputs:

> https%3A%2F%2Fapi.linkedin.com%2Fv1%2Fpeople%2F~

### **[EDIT]: After OP Clarification: If there are `~` in the middle somewhere**

Use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) to put back the character `~`:

```
<?php
   $URL = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name';
   echo str_replace('%7E','~',urlencode($URL));
?>
```

This outputs:

> https%3A%2F%2Fapi.linkedin.com%2Fv1%2Fpeople%2F~%3A%28id%2Cfirst-name%2Clast-name

Comment: trouble is sometimes is need to do an url like this : https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name) so the ~ isnt always at the end

Comment: sorry :)
sometimes the answer is so simple yet elusive. thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Encode the string, then decode the sequence only for the `~`. If you want, you may define a constant that holds the URL-encoded value for that character and replace it.

```
define('TILDE_URLENCODE', urlencode('~')); // Or '%7E'
$url = str_replace(TILDE_URLENCODE, '~', urlencode($url));
```